# How to pass PAT Environment Variables from self-hosted runner to actions/checkout in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

github actions, PAT Environment Variable does not work from self hosted runner

I have [Action runner controller running](https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller) in kubernetes.
created `GITHUB PAT` and added `GH_PAT` and `MY_TEST` Environment variables in my self-hosted runner.
I can reach them during workflow

[image]

but somehow I cannot use my GH_PAT for `actions/checkout@v3`.
when I use my `GITHUB PAT` from secrets everything works fine

```
- name: Checkout argocd repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: leaderbet/argocd
    token: ${{secrets.GH_PAT}} 
    ref: master
```

but when I try to get it from self-hosted runner's Environment variables

```
- name: Checkout argocd repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
    repository: leaderbet/argocd
    token: $GH_PAT  # `GH_PAT` is a secret that contains your PAT
    ref: master
```

I got next error

```
Fetching the repository
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
  Waiting 10 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
  Waiting 20 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

Any advice how should I pass my `GH_PAT` variable to `actions/checkout@v3` to make it work?

Comment: Did you try using `${{env.GH_PAT}}` instead of `$GH_PAT`? If I'm not mistaken, using `$VAR` when sending inputs to an action doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code/commands and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see _[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500)_ and _[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_ for why. For instructions on formatting see _[How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)_.

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes, I have tried `${{env.GH_PAT}}`, but it's empty. @hakre thank you, will change it.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks man, with your help I realized I need to export variable to ENV `run: echo "GH_PAT=$(echo $GH_PAT)" >> $GITHUB_ENV`. now passing `${{env.GH_PAT}}` is working

Comment: Nice! Share the answer with the solution :D